# Wicked pdf not rendering header/footer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for generating `pdf` from `html` on my rails project. It is rendering `template` but I could not manage to print `header/footer` sections. Below is my code that print only `template` section

```
render pdf: "pdf_name",
               layout: 'application',
               template: 'reports/show',
               formats: [:html],
               margin: { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 },
               disable_javascript: true,
               show_as_html: params[:debug],
               header: {
                 html: { template: 'shared/header' },
                 spacing: 10
               },
               footer: {
                 html: { template: 'shared/footer' },
                 spacing: 30,
                 line: true
               }
```

If I try to use `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string render_to_string` it show `Failed to load PDF document` error even simple `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<html><body><h1>Hello There!</h1></body></html>')` does not work.

I have tried to use `render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf, render_with_wicked_pdf` but did not success. My Rails version is `3.2.19`, `wicked_pdf` gem version is `1.1.0` and `wkhtmltopdf` version is `wkhtmltopdf-0.13.0-alpha-7b36694_linux-trusty-amd64.deb`. I also tried to use `wkhtmltopdf` version `0.12.0`.

My questions are

1. Why my above implementation does not work?
2. Why `pdf_from_string` does not work?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a version of `wkhtmltopdf` built with patched qt, which properly works with footer and header.

```
$ wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
$ tar xf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
$ sudo mv wkhtmltox /usr/local/share/
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/share/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf 1005
```

check the version:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
```

it should say:

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)
```

test it:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --footer-center 'footer' http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

you can also install the wkhtmltoimage:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/share/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage 1005
```

you can use a script like this: [wkhtmltox installer](https://gist.github.com/eendroroy/a3d9b647aa095b1bb404f7834c923fb1)

Comment: Thanks, it's made my day :)

Comment: is this working with highcharts graph, in my case, graph is not displayed with qt patched